# Windows 11 %HOMEPATH% error?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11

Just noticed a new directory "type", appears similar to Library or other special directories, but for %homepath%.  No `Properties` option appears in context menu, and there's a `Customize this folder...` shell menu entry...

[image: Context Menu]

...that results in this error:

[image: Error]

What's going on here?

Comment: What is the "new" Type - better clarity will help. Libraries are just a collection of folders and not used a lot. Nothing wrong or abnormal with my Windows 11 machines (18 months now).

Comment: are you asking what the PrintHood shortcut is?

Comment: I'm asking what the error is, since it discloses literally no specifics.

Comment: is `harri` your username or a piece of software you have installed?

Comment: @frankthomas Username

Comment: To clarify, I'm referring to the directory that is invoked when you use `Run` dialogue to call %homepath%.